# Python: can call __subclasses__() on build in types, not on custom object

Tags: python

```
class Test: pass
print(Test.__subclasses__())
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: class Test has no attribute '__subclasses__'
```

And

```
print(int.__subclasses__())
```

returns:

```
[<type 'bool'>]
```

Why can't I call **subclasses**() on my custom object?

This build in methods aren't reserver for custom types, are they?

> Each class keeps a list of weak references to its immediate subclasses. This method returns a list of all those references still alive. Example:

Comment: Do never user old-style classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to do this:-

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

# This works perfectly fine now.
print(Foo.__subclasses__())
```

The class above is a "new-style" class because it inherits from the object class. New-style classes provide a lot of extra framework that "old-style" classes do not have. One particular attribute of a new-style class is to be able to determine the subclasses of the class with the **subclasses** method.

Comment: +1 for explaining difference betweend old- and new=style classes.

Comment: Note that you don't need to inherit from `object` in Python 3. All classes are 'new-style'.